# Integral equation: $x f(x) = \int _0 ^x \int _0 ^t f(u) \ \Bbb d u \ \Bbb d t$

Tags: integration, integral-equations

Would you please find the function $f$ such that $$x f(x) = \int _0 ^x \int _0 ^t f(u) \ \Bbb d u \ \Bbb d t \quad ?$$
Thank you.

Comment: Please include the integral and any attempts that you have at a solution.  This is *not* a homework site.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Solve the differential equation $xf''(x)+2f'(x)-f(x)=0$.

Comment: The obvious starting point is to differentiate twice to get a differential equation.

Comment: The differential equation needs Bessel functions for a solution. I assume you have met them.

Comment: i tried to find f and searched this site,such as "Derivative of double integral with respect to upper limits" here.but I couldn't find f.this is not my homework.the main question was:find the ilapalce of (e^(-1/4s))and I conclude that integral and now I need to find the f as the answer of the ilaplace.thank you.

Comment: @almagest: Bessel ? Are you sure ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, I just asked Mathematica. Of course, Mathematica solutions can often be simplified/rearranged. Or maybe I made a typo :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust But I am giving up on this question after the OP's last comment. I am far from clear what his real question is.

Comment: @almagest: you were right, modified Bessel; but there is a change of variable with $\sqrt x$, which modifies the factors in the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$xf(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^tf(u)\mathrm du\mathrm dt$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$: $$f(x)+xf'(x)=\int_0^xf(u)\mathrm du$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$: $$f'(x)+f'(x)+xf''(x)=f(x)$$

Using $y$ to substitute $f(x)$: $$xy''+2y'-y=0$$

Comment: thank you.I haven't read Bessel.can I solve this equation using power series?